# Esta libreria no me reconoce QInputDialog, no entiendo

Tags: python, pyqt4

El siguiente codigo genera un error especificado mas abajo con imagen. El comando QInputDialog.getText(), no esta generando ni siendo reconocido. EL codigo es de un curso en el que la aplicacion funciona correctamente. Buscando la solucion para poder generar lo intencionado en el codigo.

Ademas estoy aprendiendo y este codigo me a generado varios partiendo del primero.

El problema ocurre cuando ejecuto la aplicacion me genera el siguiente error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juan/Trabajos Propios/PySide2/Curso de PyQt/lanz_listWgS.py", line 22, in editList
    newtext, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Escribe Nuevo Texto", "Escribe Nuevo Texto")
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(alistarItems, str, str)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, str, str, PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode, str=PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode.Normal, PySide2.QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags=Default(Qt.WindowFlags), PySide2.QtCore.Qt.InputMethodHints=PySide2.QtCore.Qt.InputMethodHint.ImhNone)
```

[image: demostración de error]

```
python  
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
            
            # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'listWidgetS.ui'
            #
            # Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.12.1
            #
            # WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
            
            from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
            
            try:
                _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
            except AttributeError:
                def _fromUtf8(s):
                    return s
            
            try:
                _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
                def _translate(context, text, disambig):
                    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
            except AttributeError:
                def _translate(context, text, disambig):
                    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
            
            class Ui_Dialog(object):
                def setupUi(self, Dialog):
                    Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
                    Dialog.resize(735, 337)
                    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
                    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 111, 31))
                    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
                    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
                    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 201, 27))
                    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
                    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
                    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 130, 97, 27))
                    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
                    self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(Dialog)
                    self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 50, 341, 271))
                    self.listWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listWidget"))
                    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
                    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 170, 97, 27))
                    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
                    self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
                    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 210, 97, 27))
                    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
                    self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
                    self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 250, 97, 27))
                    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
            
                    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
                    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
            
                def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
                    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
                    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Escriba un Path:", None))
                    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "&Añadir", None))
                    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "&Editar", None))
                    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "&Borrar", None))
                    self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Borrar &Todo", None))
            
            
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                import sys
                app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
                Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
                ui = Ui_Dialog()
                ui.setupUi(Dialog)
                Dialog.show()
                sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
        #Esta Seccion Hace parte del archivo.py llamado lanzador.
        #Este Archivo.py lanzara la interfaz que trae el codigo de arriba.
        
        from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
        import sys
        from listWidgetS import *
        from PySide2.QtWidgets import QInputDialog
        
        class alistarItems(QtGui.QDialog):
            def __init__(self, parent=None):
                QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
                self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
                self.ui.setupUi(self)
                QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.addList)
                QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.editList)
                QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.deleteList)
                QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_4, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.deleteListAll)
            #Funciones
            def addList(self):
                self.ui.listWidget.addItem(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
                self.ui.lineEdit.setText('')
                self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()
            def editList(self):
                row = self.ui.listWidget.currentRow()
                newtext, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Escribe Nuevo Texto", "Escribe Nuevo Texto")
                if ok and (len(newtext)!=0):
                    self.ui.listWidget.takeItem(self.ui.listWidget.currentRow())
                    self.ui.listWidget.insertItem(row,QListWidgetItem=newtext)
                self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()
            def deleteList(self):
                self.ui.listWidget.takeItem(self.ui.listWidget.currentRow())
                self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()
            def deleteListAll(self):
                self.ui.listWidget.clear()
                self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()
        
        if __name__=="__main__":
            app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
            myapp = alistarItems()
            myapp.show()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Si miramos el error, dice

```
Supported signatures: PySide2.QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, str, str, PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode, str=PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode.Normal, PySide2.QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags=Default(Qt.WindowFlags), PySide2.QtCore.Qt.InputMethodHints=PySide2.QtCore.Qt.InputMethodHint.ImhNone
```

El inicio, `Supported signature`, nos informa de que la función necesita unos determinados tipos en sus argumentos.

Ahora, si contamos los argumentos **que no tienen valor por defecto** (no tienen un `=`), tenemos

```
PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, str, str, PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode
```

Son 4 argumentos **obligatorios**. Ahora, si miramos tu código:

```
QInputDialog.getText(self, "Escribe Nuevo Texto", "Escribe Nuevo Texto")
```

vemos que estás intentando llamar a la función **con solo 3 argumentos**.

Consultando la documentación, vemos los posibles valores de `EchoMode`:

- QLineEdit.Normal

  > Display characters as they are entered.
- QLineEdit.NoEcho

  > Do not display anything. This may be appropriate for passwords where even the length of the password should be kept secret.
- QLineEdit.Password

  > Display platform-dependent password mask characters instead of the characters actually entered.
- QLineEdit.PasswordEchoOnEdit

  > Display characters as they are entered while editing otherwise display characters as with Password.

A falta de mas detalles, suponemos que quieres usar el valor `Normal`, de forma que los caracteres se muestren según se escriben.

Entonces, tu llamada quedaría

```
QInputDialog.getText(self, "Escribe Nuevo Texto", "Escribe Nuevo Texto", QtGui.QLineEdit.Normal)
```